# xcode 7.3.1, getting error memcpy no member in namespace

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, memcpy

when trying to compile some c / c++ code for iOS.  Getting

```
No member named 'memcpy' in namespace 'std::__1'; did you mean 'wmemcpy'?
```

Have tried the compiler settings with no luck.

This is in the memory file in the tool chain.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to add

`#include <cstring>`

hope it helps